# Защита файлов от просмотра/редактирования с помощью Python

Tags: python, шифрование, zip

Есть скрипт на Python который работает с повышенными правами, а рядом с ним папка со множеством .VB, .ps1, .bat файлов которые скрипт запускает в процессе своей работы. Стало понятно что "лиходей" может заменить содержимое этих файлов своими и выполнить любой код от имени администратора.
Задачи стоит две:

- Как зашифровать файлы/директорию но при этом дать на чтение доступ скрипту?
- Как дать возможность мне, без "танцев с бубном" изменять содержимое .VB, .ps1, .bat файлов т.к. переписываются они очень часто?

Из-за второго пункта обычное шифрование фалов через hashlib не подходит. Придется каждый раз расшифровывать файл, редактировать и заново шифровать.
Думал в сторону обычного zip архивирования файлов с паролем. Но в модуле zipfile для Python не нашел функции шифрования.
Может есть какие-то готовые решения?

Comment: Не нужно ничего шифровать, у любого файла/каталога есть ACL, вот в нём и прописывайте нужные доступы нужным пользователям в момент установки приложения http://timgolden.me.uk/python/win32_how_do_i/add-security-to-a-file.html

Comment: Слишком не надежно. Например, перезагрузиться с загрузочной флешки и поменять файлы дело 2х минут. Или сбросить пароль локального администратора, заменить файлы и уже иметь права доменного администратора. Нужно что-то надежнее.

Comment: Загрузочная флешка блокируется через Secure Boot или просто запароленный биос, сброс пароля тоже просто так не делается. Если вы настолько всего боитесь, то почему думаете, что шифрование не расшифруют, если пожелают?

Comment: Данный скрипт работает на 730ПК и за каждым ПК проследить практически невозможно. Плюс в Лесу AD есть целая толпа людей с правами администратора которым так же не стоит в дальнейшем видеть эти файлы.

Comment: Значит кто-то где-то налажал с настройкой AD, раз администраторов оказалась целая толпа)

Comment: Не совсем. Просто в головном офисе целый этаж Сис Админов, Программистов, Тех. Поддержки и СБ. Плюс филиалы по всей стране где тоже сидят Сис админы.

Answer (score 0):

Я плохо смотрел мануалы по модулю ZipFile.
Для меня вполне подходит вариант с обычным шифрованием .zip архива.
Все файлы в одном архиве. Элементарно редактировать и очень простой способ взаимодействия через скрипт Python.

```
from zipfile import ZipFile

zip_arh = 'test.zip'
passwd = '123'

with ZipFile(zip_arh) as zf:
  zf.extractall(pwd=bytes(passwd,'utf-8'))
  scr = zf.read(f'test.ps1',pwd=bytes(passwd,'utf-8')).decode()
```

Comment: Что помешает человеку прочитать этот самый passwd = '123' из вашего Python-скрипта, расшифровать zip-архив и сделать всё что хочется?

Comment: То что скрипт откомпилирован в exe файл.

Comment: Что помешает распаковать exe-файл и достать из него пароль? Многие exe-файлы можно открыть через самый обыкновенный WinRar, не говоря уже о более специализированных инструментах для декомпиляции.

Comment: @andreymal 3.9 и 3.10 не декомпилятся на данный момент. если не хранить там строку в открытом виде, то на пару лет хватит.

Comment: тем не менее я бы положил для каждого скрипта или на архив отсоединенную ассиметричную электронную подпись или хотябы хеш суммы файлов посчитал и вкомпилил в экзешник.